# Disable Angular Material slider and set slider value to minimum value

Tags: css, angular, slider, material-design

If you have a slider like this

```html
<mat-slider disabled min="1" max="10" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

you have the following problem: The slider should be disabled, but it isn't (from the styling perspective). Only if you click on the knob, he gets the disabled state (in my real project). If you click on another area the knob looks like an enabled one again.

Disabled slider with a value set:
[image: Disabled slider with a value set]

Disabled slider with minimum value:
[image: Disabled slider with minimum value]

Both slider are disabled, but the styling is differently.

Since the value is one and the minimum slider value is also one the system applies the `mat-slider-min-value` class in addition to the `mat-slider-disabled` class, which overwrites the `background-color` of `mat-slider-thumb` item.

On the other side, if you set the value e.g. to two you get the disabled state as it should be. But that would confuse the user if you have such a value.

I tried to not set a value, but that doesn't change the behavior. Furthermore, I tried to add this CSS to my components CSS to overwrite the color

```css
.mat-slider-disabled .mat-slider-track-background, .mat-slider-disabled .mat-slider-track-fill, .mat-slider-disabled .mat-slider-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26) !important;
}
```

but it doesn't get applied.

So how can I get the "disabled" appearing for the slider?

**Edit:**

If I put the above CSS into the general CSS file (*styles.scss* in my case), then I get my desired appearing. But for me this still looks like an error in the slider appearing for the disabled case. Perhaps there is a better solution/fix for this.

Comment: Do you need this? - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gadkoh

Comment: I tried to work on a simple stackblitz project, slider is getting disabled properly https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-slider-disable

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: Compare the styling with the initial state and a value set. Switch between enabled and disabled and you will see that the correct CSS is only applied if the slider has another value than the initial/minimal value. In my case the styling with the initial state looks the same like if the slider would have a value. Don't know why you have a yellow slider here.

Comment: @manishgdev: Yes, it is disabled, but the styling differes: initial (disabled) state vs. any other (disabled) state

Comment: pls, does anybody know how to make slider not to add mat-slider-min-value class? why the minimum value should be allways visually emphasized?

Comment: @orhor: I've kind of solved it with CSS (see question). But the class is still applied.